# Log in page on index.html

Tags: php, html, redirect, authentication

I currently have a login system on my index page; which is working fine. However, when a user logs in, it directs them to a completely new page which i don't want. How to I implement the code so that;

A) the user stays on the index page after login
B) A welcome message "Welcome...." displays on the index page.

index.html

```
<div id="leftmenu_top"></div>

                <div id="leftmenu_main"> 
                <div class="login">

                <h3>Please login below</h3>
                <br/>

                <!--Log in form-->
                <html>

<form action='login.php' method='POST'>
Username: <input type='text' name='username'><br>
Password: <input type='password' name='password'><br>
<input type='submit' value='Log in'>
</form>
</html>
```

login.php

```
<?php

session_start();

$username = strtolower($_POST['username']);
$password = strtolower($_POST['password']);

if ($username&&$password)
{

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Couldn't connect");
mysql_select_db("a&e") or die("Couldn't find db");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");

$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if ($numrows==!0)
{
//code to login

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $dbusername = $row['username'];
    $dbpassword = $row['password'];
}

//check to see if they match
if($username==$dbusername&&$password==$password)
{
echo "Welcome $username";
$_SESSION['username']=$username;

}
else
echo "incorrect password";

}
else
    die("That user does not exist");


}
else
    die("please provide a  username and password");

?>
```

Comment: You want too google AJAX friend.

Comment: And after that: context escaping for the database, or prepared statements, and proper password hashing.

Comment: oh that doesn't sound fun!

Comment: you will need to change ur index.html to index.php.. than once the user logs in redirect it to your index.php also store a session for that login .. in your index.php check the session if the user had already logged in.. if he is display welcome page or display login form..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    $query = "SELECT Username, Password FROM tbluser
              WHERE Username = '$username' AND Password = '$password'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
       if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0){
        echo ' Password/Username is not found';
    }else {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
          echo 'You are logged in </br>';


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea, I think you should give it a try

Comment: @SH Ok, just check it now.

Comment: Just include an input form

Comment: still nothing, think I'm confused with the PHP side and getting it to display on the index

Comment: yeah, i know. It's not working don't want to waste any more of your time. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

put

```
header('Location: index.php');
```

at the bottom of the login.php

Also, if you add ?success at the end of this link and then call it in your index page it will display the message you want. Change the above code to

```
header('Location: index.php?status=success');
```

and then in you index page put this where you want the message to appear

```
<?php If($_GET['status'] = "success") { ?>
    <p>This is a welcome message</p>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: how would i display if the login was successful, echo welcome (username);

Comment: do you know how i would echo the username on the website @phpNoOb